# Removing constraints of Java array

Tags: java, class, array

> Java arrays only allow subscripts to range between 0 and N-1 for an array of size N.
>
> The class below aims to remove that constraint by allowing the class
>   user to specify the valid subscripts for a one dimensional array of
>   integers.

```
public class BoundedIntArray {

 private int[] array;

 // further state required here

 public BoundedIntArray() {…}

 public BoundedIntArray(int high) {…}

 public BoundedIntArray(int low, int high) {…}



 public int length() {…}

 public int getElement(int index) {…}

 public void putElement(int index, int value) {…}

 public void resize(int low, int high) {…}
```

}

This is a question I was given in a recent exam. I'm struggling to understand quite what the problem is and what the above class is trying to accomplish.

What's wrong with only being allowed to range between 0 and N-1? Why would you want to exceed the size of the array and go beyond N or <0?

What do *low* and *high* refer to?

These are the exam questions:

> > a).    The class needs further private members to identify the upper and lower bounds of the array. Provide appropriate declarations for
> >     this state.  [4 marks]
>
> b).    Supply an implementation of the three constructors for the
>   BoundedIntArray class
>   [6 marks]
>
> c).   Provide an implementation for each method (with appropriate
>   exceptions) for the BoundedIntArray class.
>   [15 marks]
>
> d).   Explain how to generalise this class so that arrays of any type
>   can be used rather than just int’s.
>   [5 marks]

Comment: I see the beginnings of an exam question, but not an actual question.  `low` and `high` appear to be the lowest and highest numbers that you can pass as an `index` to `getElement` and `putElement`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey see update :)

Comment: As a guess - it asks to make an "array" whose indexes run from `low` to `high` instead of `0` to `n`. This is probably to calm down all those people who throw tantrums when confronted with the fact that array indexing is 0-based in most (popular) languages.

Comment: @Ordous: It's an exam question.  It's only purpose is probably to see if you understand how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

A real world example might be waist sizes.  Men's shorts might come in sizes from 28 inches to 50 in 1-inch increments.  Instead of everywhere in your program saying, `sizes[i + 27]` you create an "array" with indicies 28-50 (and thus size=21) and not have to worry about offsets.

```
BoundedIntArray sizes = new BoundedIntArray(28, 50);

void addToCount(int size) {
    int count = sizes.get(size);
    sizes.set(size, count + 1);
}
```

Presumably the BoundedIntArray would allocate an array when it is constructed of a suitable size to never throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException for the defined range.

Comment: Why is there no size declaration in private int[] array;?

Comment: @MartinRand That's just Java syntax.  If you want an array of 6 items you say `private int[] myArray = new int[6];`  The size of the array is not part of the type.  What you are asking for is called a "dependent type."  If you want that, look at Idris. http://www.idris-lang.org/

Comment: If the lower bound is, say, 28, wouldn't we be wasting memory for 0-28, which is declared but not used?